# How to obtain a list from a list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have obtained below list obtained by BS4.

```
a = [<td>(Range 5683 - 5723 ft)</td>,
 <td>32° 56' 17'' N</td>,
 <td>Ut</td>,
 <td>Na</td>,
 <td>eGo</td>]
```

I am trying to obtain a list of ['Ut', 'Na', 'eGo']
An individual string such as 'Ut' could be obtained by using the code

```
a[2].text = 'Ut'
```

How could I use a for loop to obtain a list directly?
I tried the below code but the logic has some problem and I could not get the correct result.

```
row = []
for i in a[x]:
    for x in range(3):

        row.append(i)
row
```

output = ['Ut', 'Ut', 'Ut']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mix of list comprehension and array slicing:

```
row = [tag.text for tag in a[2:]]
print(row) # => ['Ut', 'Na', 'eGo']
```